# Questions in the paper "Morita endomorphism algebras of generators"

Tags: rt.representation-theory, morita-theory

I am reading this paper "Morita endomorphism algebras of generators", the link is here:http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10468-016-9601-z

There are two quesions I can't understand:

1. on page 751, it says "assume there is a faithful projective and injective right ideal $eA$. Then for any faithful projective injective module $P$ in $modA$, there are monomorphisms $eA\rightarrow P^r$ and $P \rightarrow eA^s$ for some $r,s>0$". How can we get monomorphisms  $eA\rightarrow P^r$ and $P \rightarrow eA^s$ for any  faithful projective injective module $P$？
2. on page 752, it gives an example, I post it here.
   [image]

My quesion is: how can we judge whether $B$ is a Morita algebra with base algebra $(e_1+e_2)B(e_1+e_2)$? How can we see if $\operatorname{Hom}_{A_2}(D(A_2),A_2)$ is still faithful?

Comment: may I ask why you ask so many questions related to dominant dimension ? Do you write you thesis about that?

Comment: @Mare I'm a new learner of representation theory,not familiar with it and people around me are not interested in it. I want to do someting about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(answer since comment is too long)
1. One has $add(eA)=add(P)$, which are obtained just by taking the direct sum of the indecomposable non-isomorphic projective-injective modules. Thus it is immediate to get such monomorphisms.
2. You have to check that $(e_1+e_2)B$ is faithful projective-injective, that $B$ has dominant dimension at least two and that $(e_1+e_2)B(e_1+e_2)$ is selfinjective. All those things are standard calculations and can for example be done quickly by hand of by  the computer algebra system QPA (which is a package of GAP). The operation on the module $Hom_{A_2}(D(A_2),A_2)$ is explicitly known and so checking faithfulness is also straight-forward.

Comment: To quesion 1, why $add(eA)=add(P)$ for any projective injective module $P$.(for example, we just take $P$ as a indecomposable direct summand of $eA$)

Comment: But you say that P is faithful in 1.